# What is the difference between `id` and `pos` n a Spinner's OnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android-spinner

When creating a [`Spinner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html), I assign an [`OnItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) using [`setOnItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29).  When a select an item in the spinner, the [`onItemSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method is called, with arguments including `position` and `id`.

From my observations, `position` and `id` always have the same values.  Is there any difference in the meaning of these values when using an [`OnItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) with a [`Spinner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)?